# Google Analytics Offline tracking

Tags: google-analytics, intranet, event-tracking

I need to track information with Google analytics from within an intranet site and people consuming it may not have internet access.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Best option would be to go back to a server that has access and call the apis within there, that is if you have an app installed on the internal network.

Comment: @Vince that would take a huge development effort, or am I wrong?

Comment: You could act as a proxy for the analytics calls, which would limit the work.  Basically take the header & data from the call into the box and pass that into the analytics call.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be to keep track of all events in an intranet server (the server that serves that intranet site could be an ideal one to do that), and then from that intranet server you can send HTTP request to google analytics i.e. proxy the analytics AJAX from clients to Google Analytics server

You can debug the request details using browser developer tools or else you can also try changing the URL of GA library source code to your intranet site that would proxy the request to google Analytics.